# Dynamic table mapping in EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, ef-core-7.0

I've 2 tables Test_1 and Test_2 in the database which is mapped to single model class Test

```
public class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

I've created the Dbcontext as

```
public class TestDbContext : DbContext
{
    public TestDbContext(DbContextOptions<TestDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<Test> Tests { get; set; }
}
```

The suffix 1 or 2 is determined by the user input. When the user input is 1, data should to inserted to Test_1 while using the below code. Is there a way to dynamically map the tables in EntityFrameworkCore?

```
_dbcontext.Tests.Add(newrecord);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't map dynamically like that. I have two potential solutions though.

### Create a base class and derive from it

Create new entities derived from the original `Test` class, and use them in your context:

```cs
public abstract class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
}

public class Test1 : Test { }
public class Test2 : Test { }

public class TestDbContext : DbContext
{
    public TestDbContext(DbContextOptions<TestDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<Test1> Test1s { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Test2> Test2s { get; set; }
}
```

Now you need an `if` or `switch` statement to determine which one to use:

```cs
if(version == 1) 
{
    CreateTest<Test1>(id, username);
}
else if(version == 2)
{
    CreateTest<Test2>(id, username);
}

await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

And a method to create the test object and insert, leveraging the [`DbContext.Set<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.set?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#system-data-entity-dbcontext-set-1) method:

```cs
private void CreateTest<TTestType>(int id, string username)
    where TTestType : Test, new()
{
    var test = new TTestType();
    test.Id = id;
    test.Username = username;

    _context.Set<TTestType>().Add(test);
}
```

### Don't use two different tables

It seems to me this would be a lot simpler if you just add a version column to the `Test` entity and table:

```cs
public abstract class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public int Version { get; set; } // 1 or 2
}
```

A secondary benefit of this is that you can add versions 3, 4, 5 etc. whenever you need with very few changes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was able to map the tables using linq2db https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db